# Nokia HERE maps: Calculate displacement between two coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, here-api

I am trying to calculate the displacement between two coordinates in meters, Is there a function in `here` maps that does this calculation?

If not, how do I effectively calculate distance between the two coordinate points in JavaScript.

Comment: My guess is this was -1 simply because it was a short question. There's an extended discussion on this type of thing going on in [meta currently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway I found what I was looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10054282/1161412 .(Now I just have to implement the same in JS) Although, I would still like to know if there are any functions in `HERE` maps for the same. So, I am going to keep this question open for a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this php function (based on Vincenty's algorithm), and it works great in calculating displacement between 2 coordinates,

```
<?php
function vincentyGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000){
        // convert from degrees to radians
        $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
        $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
        $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
        $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

        $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
        $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
        pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);
        $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

        $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);
        return $angle * $earthRadius;
    }
?>
```

**Call:**

```
<?php $distance_in_meters = vincentyGreatCircleDistance(53.6235,-1.34307, 51.6554, -2.3445 ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [distance()](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate.html#topic-apiref__Coordinate-distance-method) method in the `nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate` class. An example of usage can be found in the **Find Nearest Marker** example on the [HERE Maps Community](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#find-nearest-marker) pages on GitHub.