# acos(1) returns NAN in some conditions

Tags: php, math, floating-point, trigonometry, nan

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$lat1 = 35.697959;
$lat2 = 35.697959;
$lon1 = 139.707085;
$lon2 = 139.707085;
$theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
var_dump($dist); // returns 1

$dist = acos($dist); 
var_dump($dist); // returns NAN
```

As you can see from the comments, `$dist` is equal to `1` after the calculation, but when I apply `acos()` it returns `NAN`.

If I try to replicate it manually, it works just fine:

```
$x = 1;
$x = acos($x);
var_dump($x);  // returns 0 as expected
```

What's going on here and how can I fix it?

[Here's the same code](https://3v4l.org/2NFZr) in an online shell, so you can see that it actually returns those values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems that the problem is related to precision. If I make sure that `$dist` is within `[-1,1]` range, it works fine:

```
$dist = acos(min(max($dist,-1.0),1.0));
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/dlunK

Comment: You genius! this saved me a lot of annoyance once I found the source of the NAN.

Comment: An alternative answer would be  round($dist,12) which has an advantage that it is only fixing the rounding issue. Other errors such as $dist=8 would still flag up.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `$dist` is a little greater than 1, due to rounding.

```
var_export($dist);
```

gives me

```
1.0000000000000002
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason why `var_export()` shows the value more precisely than `var_dump()`?

Comment: For me, print_r() shows 1, but var_dump() is showing the full precision