# How to calculate distance with lat long dynamically using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

In location table i have these columns:lat,long,date,userid

i want to display how much distance covered by particular user with my
location table.

How to calculate distance in kilometer with help of lat long and query
 for this to display this data front side.

please refer below image for the same.[image: location table data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider this a duplicate question.

Please see: [Measuring the distance between two coordinates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php)

Or google the Haversine formula.

Comment: how to use it for dynamic values

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  The formulas listed in the answer on the question that I linked to has a function which you can use.  the prototype is (lat,long,lat,long, radius of earth) which can be used in php once you pull the data.  Alternatively you could implement the same math to generate an additional field in mysql.