# How to calculate the distance from multiple latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: php, arrays, geolocation, distance, latitude-longitude

I have the following arrays:

```
$latitude = ['9.9663755','10.1883153','9.9689272','10.1109653' ,'10.1883153','10.1883153']
$longitude = ['76.288569','76.4512288','76.2890601','76.3541268','76.4512288','76.4512288']
```

How do I get the total distance travelled  with these points.

Comment: Somewhat off topic but *"longotude"* isn't spelt properly, it should be *"longitude"*.

Comment: lat and long having totally four points FROM and TO. Why you are having 6,6?

Comment: This site is not coding service - please try to do that yourself (and share the code you tried) and if you failed I will post the php code of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Except for the array handling this is a duplicate of [Measuring the distance between two coordinates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php) (to calculate the distance). I would suggest something like:

```
$dist=0;
$alen=count($latitude);

for ($i=1;$i<$alen;$i++) {
   $lat=$latitude[$i];
   $lon=$longotude[$i];
   $frlat=$latitude[$i-1];
   $frlon=$longotude[$i-1]
  // calculate distance according to the link above
  // pass in $frlat, $frlon and $lat, $lon to determine a single
  // segment distance. store in $calcdist)
  $dist+=$caldist;
  $llat=$lat;
  $
}
```

Comment: Rasa Mohmed -- Your proposed edit does not take into account that the loop should only be run 4 times since the first element in the array is the starting point. So you are adding 1-0, 2-1, 3-2 and 4-3 elements to get the distance that's why $i<$alen is used instead of $i<=$alen as you suggest.